# Problem in implementing Axios.get in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am new to react and I want to make an Axios.get() request based on a function parameter. This is what I tried.

```
 const mentorName = (value) => {
    try {
      Axios.get(
        `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/consultations/${value}`
      ).then(res => {
        if (res.status !== 200 || res.data.status !== "success") {
          console.log(res)
          return
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

But It didn't work as res was not printed in console. What is wrong in this?

The code that worked fine is:

```
const mentorName = (value) => {
    try {
      const res = Axios.get(
        `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/consultations/${value}`
      )
        if (res.status !== 200 || res.data.status !== "success") {
          console.log(res)
          return
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

The below code worked fine but returns information wrapped in a promise. How to access it now because res.data is not a valid property.

Comment: Have you checked what the status code of the response actually is? As the `console.log` will not happen if that code is not specifically 200. By looking at the code you have shown, the problem could also be in the API.

Comment: I have edited my question, please see it again. Status code is 200.

Comment: Have you tried `awaiting` the `axios.get()`?

Comment: Yes I did. But it shows the error that Objects are not valid as a React child. I searched on net and the solution was to use useEffect with async. But how to use it effectively for a function call?

Comment: In the first example, if the status code is 200 and data.status is "success", you won't see any output. That's how you wrote it. How about showing output in an `else` case to your `if` statement? Your second "working" example is a distraction. You're testing that `somePromise.status` is not 200. It isn't. It's undefined, so it is no surpise that the `if` statement "works".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this with `async/await`.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const mentorName = async value => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/v1/consultations/${value}`);
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

In the console.log inside `try` block you can check for the `api response`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mentorName = (value) => {
    try {
      Axios.get(
        `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/consultations/${value}`
      ).then(res => {
        if (res.status !== 200 || res.data.status !== "success") {
          console.log(res)
          return
        }
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

above code doesn't print because of the if condition, it is likely that the status is going to be 200 most of the time and anything apart from 200 would drill down to catch block

the reason it is printing promise in below code is because, it is a promise waiting to be fulfilled and the comparison / condition you have put up is very much fine because res is a promise and res.status is undefined

```
const mentorName = (value) => {
    try {
      const res = Axios.get(
        `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/consultations/${value}`
      )
        if (res.status !== 200 || res.data.status !== "success") {
          console.log(res)
          return
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

tweak the code to include an else block and you can always see something printed in console

```
const mentorName = (value) => {
        try {
          Axios.get(
            `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/consultations/${value}`
          ).then(res => {
            if (res.status !== 200 || res.data.status !== "success") {
              console.log(res)
              return
            } else {
              console.log(res);
            }
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      }
```

I do not recommend using async/await due to one single and pressing reason, that the UI thread is put on hold until the async call is resolved. just to make it look like a synchronous call. stick on to the promise way.

Comment: All good except the last bit: "the UI thread is put on hold until the async call is resolved" I don't understand what you're trying to say here. In JS in the browser, using async/await won't "hold the UI thread" and there's little difference between using `Promise.then` and using `async/await` in this case.

Comment: the subtle difference between async/await and promise is that, the promises would not wait until the asynchronous execution is winded up and returned with response on the other hand async await does. when the execution stack encounters "async" (in layman terms) it pauses the execution and waits for the micro tasks to complete its execution (async/await is just a syntactic sugar over promises to achieve synchronous like execution).